# How to pick "full/thumbnail" images in the loop?

Tags: php, posts, loop, post-thumbnails

I am picking the latest posts through the WordPress loop using the below code, but it's picking all images at `full` size:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <!-- Post Start -->
        <div id="post">
            <a class="post_image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                    the_post_thumbnail('full');
                else : ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/No-Thumbnail-Available.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
            <h2 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <span class="post_desc"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Post Start -->
    <?php endwhile;
else: ?>
    <p class="error"><?php _e('Sorry, No Article Is Available Here...'); ?></p>
<?php endif;
```

I want to pick the `full` image for the first post of the Loop and `thumbnail` images for all the rest of the posts in the Loop. I am able to do it via CSS, but that is not SEO friendly. I am using the below code but it's not working:

```
$first = true;
foreach ( $obj as $value ) {
    if ( $first ) { ?>
        <!-- Post Start -->
        <div id="post">
            <a class="post_image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                    the_post_thumbnail('full');
                else : ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/No-Thumbnail-Available.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
            <h2 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <span class="post_desc"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Post Start -->
        <?php $first = false;
    } else { ?>
        <!-- Post Start -->
        <div id="post">
            <a class="post_image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                else : ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/No-Thumbnail-Available.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
            <h2 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <span class="post_desc"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Post Start -->
    <?php }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using the traditional `$i` iterator (untested) but I can't see why this wouldn't work..

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $i++;
    if ( $i == 1 ): ?>
    <!-- First Post -->
    <div id="post">
        <a class="post_image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/No-Thumbnail-Available.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
        <h2 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <span class="post_desc"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<?php else: // else $i == 1 ?>
    <!-- All Other Posts -->
    <div id="post">
        <a class="post_image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/No-Thumbnail-Available.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
        <h2 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <span class="post_desc"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; // endif for $i == 1 ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I wouldn't put the if at the beginning since the remainder of the content is the same. I'd suggest:
 
    `if ( has_post_thumbnail() && $i == 1 ) { full }`
    `elseif ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { thumb }`
    `else { noImg }`

Comment: @NathanFitzgerald Thanks. You are awesome. I got what I want...!!!